# Android exhibition mode --> Detect user inactivity

Tags: android

I will first explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I wanna use some android devices (10-12) as exhibition devices. The will be always on power and my visitors can play with them. When a device is inactive for a while, I wanna pop up a full screen video playing. The video file must be updated once in a while.

What I have thought so far is to develop a background service app that will update the file of the video I wanna show. And I will create/send an intent to trigger my video player.

What's bothering me is how to detect user inactivity from the whole device. Is this even possible? I know how to do it from my activities, but here I want it for the whole device. Any ideas? Keep in my mind that it is only for my devices, so I can have any setup for them needed (install any kind of management system or root my devices).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just an idea: could you register a receiver for screen off with the highest priority (999 i think) then cancel that broadcast before the OS gets it. This might keep the screen on or it might not, I don't know but... if aborting the broadcast keeps the screen on, you know there have been however-many minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Your approach works fine!

[Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416656/i-cant-start-an-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver/13417250#13417250

is more or less the implementation

Answer (score 1):

you can add a runnable that get the system time and compare with the last time when the client touch the screen. Something like this:

```
private Runnable timeChecker = new Runnable()
 {

  public void run()
  {
      //PseudoCode
       if(getTime()-lastTime > TIME_IS_INACTIVE)
       {
          //do something

        }
  }
};
```

Comment: But how do I know whe the client touched the screen?

Comment: set an onClickListener to your main layout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html