# I can't start an activity from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

I have a broadcast receiver from which, when it receives an intent, I would like to start/resume an activity. Up to point to start the activity everything works fine, I get the intent etc.

But I cannot start my activity.

Here is my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.imgzine.testing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WebViewActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.imgzine.testing.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the activity I'm trying to start:

```
package com.imgzine.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Log.w("DEBUG", "Hello, I'm a webview");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}

}
```

And here is the part of my broadcast receiver from where I try to start the activity:

```
                    Log.w("DEBUG", "Hello, I receive.");
        Intent webviewintent = new Intent(webviewcontext,
        WebViewActivity.class);
        webviewintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        webviewintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        webviewintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        webviewcontext.startActivity(webviewintent);
```

I have to clarify here that webviewcontext is the context of my main activity and I pass it here through the constructor of the broadcast receiver. I create the broadcastreceiver in the main activity:

```
 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyPhoneReceiver(context);
 registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

However the activity does not start.. Here is the log I get:

```
11-16 12:47:36.144: W/DEBUG(818): Hello, I receive.
11-16 12:47:36.144: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.imgzine.testing/.WebViewActivity }
```

Any ideas are more that welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(webviewcontext,WebViewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
webviewcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was the context.

The following works:

```
webviewcontext = context.getApplicationContext();
```

(context is the context I get from onReceive)